# Msgpack::object to JSON string C++

Tags: c++, json, msgpack

My code looks like following:

```
msgpack::unpacked msg;
msgpack::unpack(msg, args.data(), args.size());

msgpack::object obj = msg.get();

// How to convert "obj" to JSON string format here?
```

And I want to convert that object to a JSON string. How can I perform that? I don't know the type of the elements of the object by the way, they're dynamically set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator<<` of `msgpack::object` outputs MessagePack objects in a human-readable format that happens to match JSON. You can use `std::stringstream` to store that output in a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <sstream>

unsigned char a[] = {0x82,0xa7,'c','o','m','p','a','c','t',0xc3,0xa6,'s','c','h','e','m','a',0};

int main() {
        msgpack::unpacked msg;
        msgpack::unpack(msg, (char*)a, sizeof(a));

        msgpack::object obj = msg.get();

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << obj;
        std::string demo = ss.str();

        std::cout << "As string: " << demo << "\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
As string: {"compact":true,"schema":0}
```

For this to work well, your `msgpack::object` should not contain anything for which there is no equivalent in JSON (for example, extension types).

[Reference](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v_2_0_cpp_json)

[Implementation](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/blob/be4d971c62798eb59f8455dc77a4529748bcd08f/include/msgpack/v1/object.hpp#L396)